# As space expands, does this not imply that time also expands?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, spacetime, time, space-expansion

According to General Relativity, space and time are aspects / dimensions of a unified whole. If the speed at which **wave** energy travels through spacetime is constant, $c$, then as distance expands, should not time expand by corresponding amount? If so, then would 1 Plank time from Plank Epoch, be something like ~1 picosecond in today's space-time?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be gibberish.  What does "the speed at which energy travels through space-time" mean?

Comment: I was only attempting to be general, so the question applied to the very early universe, before electromagnetism separated.

Comment: *the question applied to the very early universe* No, your question explicitly mentions “today’s space-time”.

Comment: It also explicitly mentions Plank Epoch...

Comment: What does "today's space-time" mean?  Does it mean "today"?

Comment: Yes. I was attempting to make comparison between duration length in space-time at 1 Plank time (i.e., before light exists) versus today.

Comment: There is a book by a respected physicist that addresses something related to the title of the post: Now: The Physics of Time (W. W. Norton, 2016) ISBN 978-0-393-28523-9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s a meaningless question. Intervals of the cosmological time used in the Friedmann metric don’t change, but intervals of conformal time do. You can use any time coordinate you want in cosmology, and can make coordinate time intervals get longer, shorter, or stay the same relative to proper time intervals as the universe evolves.

Precisely *because* “space and time are aspects/dimensions of a unified whole”, what is happening to individual coordinate differences such as spatial intervals or temporal intervals has no absolute significance. Only what happens to invariant *spacetime* intervals matters.

By the way, some energy, such as that of light, travels at the speed of light, but other energy, such as the mass and kinetic energy of an electron, does not and can not.

Comment: Thanks for the last clarification. I should have said "wave energy" instead of energy.

Comment: Not all wave energy travels at the speed of light. There are “matter waves” that travel more slowly.

Comment: Despite the conventional name “speed of light”, it’s best not to think of $c$ as the speed at which some things like light move, since other things move at other speeds. I suggest thinking of it as the unique *invariant* speed (same for all inertial observers) or the universal speed limit.

Comment: I am too ignorant for this site. I was only aware of light waves and gravity waves. I am trying to learn, but perhaps you could suggest a more appropriate site.

Comment: I can’t recommend any others. I think you can learn a lot of physics from this site. Don’t get discouraged.

Comment: Much appreciated! I have already learned a lot here.

Comment: You seem to have a special interest in General Relativity, cosmology, and the early universe. These are all difficult topics, and self-learning makes them even harder. No one understands these things without a lot of effort, so don’t think that you are ignorant. A proper understanding is nearly impossible without getting into the mathematics behind them, so I encourage you to look for resources that will make that math accessible to you.

Comment: I used to be fairly adept at math when in college and grad school in mid 70s - early 80s. But then I did 35 year career as Imaging Scientist for HP. Now, I am retired and able to explore what interests me, singularities, the early universe, alternate analytical approach, Cosmic Thermodynamics.